# setNeedsDisplay for DrawRect after button press

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsrect

I have this in a custom class on my NSView and when I press a button using my drawMyRec IBAction I want to change the color of my NSRect however this is not working, can anyone help?

```
#import "myView.h"

@implementation myView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        RectColor = [[NSColor blackColor] init];
    }

    return self;
}


- (IBAction)drawMyRec:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"pressed");
    RectColor = [[NSColor blueColor] init];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}


- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
    [RectColor set];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `drawRect` function is incorrect. change to this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [RectColor set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, why are you calling `-init` on an `NSColor`? Second, you're `set`ting the color after you've drawn the rect, so it won't take affect until the next redraw. 3rd, what's `dirtyRect` when `-drawRect:` is called? Why not just fill the entire rect regardless of what's dirty?